# php/mysql dynamic menu

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I have an existing drop down menu that I am attempting to convert to PHP/MySQL to allow the client to edit the menu items. This is the structure:

Home-index.php
About Us-#
  -about.php
  -annualreport.php
  -awards.php
Services-#
  -services.php
  -loans.php

and so forth. The query I'm using is:

```
select distinct mainlinks.id as daddyid, mainlinks.title as daddytitle, mainlinks.urlink as daddyurl, babylinks.id as babyid, babylinks.title as babytitle, babylinks.urlink as babyurl from mainlinks, babylinks where mainlinks.id = babylinks.parentid order by mainlinks.listorder";
```

And the result displayed with the code below:

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
// keep track of previous maincategory
$previous_maincategory = NULL;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

        // if maincategory has changed from previouscategory then display it
        if ($previous_maincategory != $row['daddytitle']) 
        {
                echo "<strong><h2>" . strtoupper($row['daddytitle']) . "</h2></strong>";
        }

        echo '<a onclick="return confirmSubmit()" class="inside" href="deletesubcategory.php?id=';
        echo $row['babyid'];
        echo '">';
        echo $row['babytitle'];
        echo "</a>";
        echo "<br/>";

        // record what the previous category was
        $previous_maincategory = $row['daddytitle'];
}
```

It only displays the items that have a **child** element, not the parent items that **do not** have child elements. Any ideas? I'm guessing the problem is with the query where clause but I can't figure out how to grab what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `LEFT JOIN` to get items which don't have childs, try

```
select distinct mainlinks.id as daddyid, mainlinks.title as daddytitle, mainlinks.urlink as daddyurl, babylinks.id as babyid, babylinks.title as babytitle, babylinks.urlink as babyurl 
from mainlinks 
  LEFT JOIN babylinks ON mainlinks.id = babylinks.parentid
order by mainlinks.listorder;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is only grabbing items `where mainlinks.id = babylinks.parentid` meaning it will ignore items where that relationship is non-existent.

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT mainlinks.id as daddyid, mainlinks.title as daddytitle, mainlinks.urlink as daddyurl, babylinks.id as babyid, babylinks.title as babytitle, babylinks.urlink as babyurl FROM mainlinks LEFT JOIN babylinks ON mainlinks.id = babylinks.parentid ORDER BY mainlinks.listorder
```

Using a `LEFT JOIN` will tell your query to pull all the mainlinks regardless if they have a baby link, but only pull baby links that have a parent.